# Create a teams team error when using Microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I just follow this official document to excuse create a team.[Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
I also using the client credential flow and apply all the permissions advised.
In Postman, I used this message to call

```
{
   "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
   "displayName":"My Sample Team",
   "description":"My Sample Team’s Description",
   "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "userId":"xxxxx-61d8-43db-94f5-81374122dc7e"
      }
   ]
}
```

but unfortunately will get such error message, I'm fully confused on this unknown Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-02T05:32:08",
      "request-id": "2955c466-f25f-42f5-ba89-4a522c428b70",
      "client-request-id": "2955c466-f25f-42f5-ba89-4a522c428b70"
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to execute it in C# code

```
var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "My Sample Team558",
            Description = "My Sample Team’s Description558",
            Members = new TeamMembersCollectionPage() {
                new AadUserConversationMember
                {
                    Roles = new List<String>()
                    {
                        "owner"
                    },
                    UserId = "9xxxxxc9-f062-48e2-8ced-22xxxxx6dfce"
                }
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };
 var result = await graphServiceClient.Teams
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(team);
```

This async call will be executed successfully and a new teams team will be also created, but the result return null, that means I could not get the team id from the result.
I could not go to the next step, such as add a new channel etc.
I'm using `Microsoft.Graph v3.18.0.0` in my C# code。

UPDATE
Here is the accesstoken
[image]

Comment: In summary, in current graph API if you call the API without a proper permission. Such as  did not grant the permissions ,grant  admin consent, access token without a role, you will get the unknown ERROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can easily reproduce your problem. The cause of this error may be that you did not grant the necessary permissions or did not grant the admin consent for this permission.

[image]

Therefore, you need to check that you have granted the necessary **application permissions** and Permission is granted to the **admin consent**.

[image]

[image]

code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var team = new Team
{
    DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
    Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(team);
```

Comment: Yes,if we didn't set the permission will also get this unknown error. But actually I already granted all these permissions under my application.

Comment: @KevinYANG   Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: regarding to my second question,the result return null.I found this link (AddAsync(team) returns null)<https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/68>.So how should I get the team id after we request a new team via API

Comment: ,Please see the screenshot in the question UPDATE

Comment: I'm using client credential  flow to get the access token when tested in postman

Comment: @KevinYANG  The permission is not included in your token. see:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEqew.png

Comment: @KevinYANG   Your token does not have permissions, so you should check API permissions https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfDzb.png

Comment: I checked the access token in C# code, the permissions contained in Roles. How should I contain these roles to acquire token in post man?

Comment: how to get access token with roles via post man?I could get it via C# library and just follow the document to get it through post man but get this token without roles.That is why met this unknown error.

Comment: @KevinYANG  Are you saying that the token obtained through c# has permission, but the token obtained through postman does not have permission? Are you sure you are using the same app?

Comment: @KevinYANG  You need to make sure that you have completed these 2 steps:


1. Make sure that you have granted application permissions to the application and obtained the administrator's consent, as shown in the screenshot I provided.

2. Make sure that the application you use through postman and the application you grant permission are the same application.

Comment: @KevinYANG   see :https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw7YM.png

Comment: Thanks,it seems that there is no differences between the request you sent to me and my request.But I will get the access token without Roles.

Comment: Any way, it is another issue,I will put this question accepted and thanks for your help!